# How to scrape a particular element (Cheerio)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

The website code is `<div class="product__price  product__price-promo "><del>16 999</del>15 999</div>`

I need to scrape 15 999. How can I do this exactly?

I already tried to do it with selector `div.product__price` or `product__price  product__price-promo` in which case I get the result "1699915999"

If I try with selector `div.product__price > del` get the result 16999.

So far I don't know how to get 15 999

Comment: What I usually do in this situation is get the "div.product__price > del" result (16999) and replace it with a blank string in the larger result "div.product__price" or "product__price product__price-promo" (1699915999) so I'm left with what I need

Comment: either `"1699915999".slice("16999".length)` or `"1699915999".replace("16999",'')` will give you `"15999"`

Comment: but there should be a better way, maybe provide the js code

Comment: @skara9
I think there is no better way. JS code is like universal for many sites. I have `const priceSelectors` where is entered priceSelectors for many sites, and then i get price by `return priceSelectors.map(sel => this._$(sel).first().text().trim()).find(e => e.length) || null;`

So i think to just skip that site. Because i thought i do smth wrong with selecting right selector. Options to slice or replace unsuitable for me.

Comment: @RomaChalyi uh `sel => this._$(sel)[0].childNodes[1].textContent.trim()` ?

Comment: @skara9  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes')

Comment: try adding `.first()` before the `[0]`

Comment: @skara9 Same mistake, you can clone and try for yourself [link](https://runkit.com/glory6/61f02b74adea0400089eba69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const b = priceSelectors.map(sel => [...this._$(sel)[0].childNodes].find(n=>n.nodeType==3&&n.data.trim()).data.trim()).find(e=>e) || null;
```

This goes through the selectors and finds the content of the first non-whitespace text node.

Comment: Thanks, but it works for 1 priceselector, if i add one more hits previous error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes')

Comment: @RomaChalyi that means it didn't find an element with that selector

Comment: but element exists. Here's example
 `const priceSelectors = [
    'div.product__price',
'div.price'`];
Hits error

`const priceSelectors = [
    'div.product__price'`];`
Element found